# How to remove stop words and lemmatize at the same time when using spaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

When I use spaCy for cleaning data, I run the following line:

`df['text'] = df.sentence.progress_apply(lambda text: " ".join(token.lemma_ for token in nlp(text) if not token.is_stop and token.is_alpha))`

Which lemmatizes each word in the text row if the word in not a stop-word. The problem is that text.lemma_ is applied to the token after the token is checked for being a stop-word or not. Therefore, if the stop-word is not in the lemmatized form, it will not be considered stop word. For example, if I add "friend" to the list of stop words, the output will still contain "friend" if the original token was "friends". The easy solution is to run this line twice. But that sounds silly. Anyone can suggest a solution to remove the stop words that are not in the lemmatized form in the first run?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply lemmatize and only then remove stop words?

Comment: Note that you generally shouldn't do this kind of preprocessing with modern NLP models. You should just use the original, natural text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check if the `token.lemma_` is present in the `nlp.Defaults.stop_words`:

```py
if token.lemma_.lower() not in nlp.Defaults.stop_words
```

For example:

```py
df['text'] = df.sentence.progress_apply(
    lambda text: 
        " ".join(
            token.lemma_ for token in nlp(text)
                if token.lemma_.lower() not in nlp.Defaults.stop_words and token.is_alpha
        )
)
```

See a quick test:

```py
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

>>> nlp.Defaults.stop_words.add("friend") # Adding "friend" to stopword list

>>> text = "I have a lot of friends"
>>> " ".join(token.lemma_ for token in nlp(text) if not token.is_stop and token.is_alpha)
'lot friend'

>>> " ".join(token.lemma_ for token in nlp(text) if token.lemma_.lower() not in nlp.Defaults.stop_words and token.is_alpha)
'lot'
```

If you add words in uppercase to the stopword list, you will need to use `if token.lemma_.lower() not in map(str.lower, nlp.Defaults.stop_words)`.